# Automatic Workflow not triggering from SP designer

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

Using Moss 07 and SPD 07, I'm attempting to create a simple workflow that will trigger an e-mail when the status of a list item has been changed to resolved.

I created a service request list with some custom columns. This is the text that is shown:

If Service Requests:Status equal Resolved

Email Service Requests:Owner

For some reason I cannot get it to trigger and/or send an e-mail.

[alt text http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/1884/spworkflow.jpg](http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/1884/spworkflow.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide a screenshot of the SPDesigner Workflow layout (assuming this is a 1 step workflow). Its my guess that you are trying have the workflow read when the item status changes?

Comment: I added the image above, and you are correct, it is just a 1 step workflow. We are piloting SP and this is the first custom workflow that I attempted to create. Which seems simple enough, but I'm not sure if the problem is on my end, or....

Comment: Try using Email Service Request:Created By, and also are you expecting this workflow to run when created and/or modified? It seems to me you are trying to make the workflow trigger when the Status is resolved...

Do you have the workflow to start when Service Request item is modified, or only when created? (It should be the first screen when creating a workflow in SPDesigner)

Comment: I didn't want to use, Created By, because a lot of times tickets are created by one person but are for someone else. For example, I create a ticket from a phonecall, but I want that user to receive the email once the issue is resolved. And yes, I want the trigger to occur when the "Status" is "Resolved".

Comment: I missed the "Automatically start this workflow when a new item is created" and other options. I had that option checked, so the workflow was starting right away, but since the status was initiated, the workflow completed and didn't do anything. Then the workflow wouldn't start again so no e-mails were created.

Comment: I changed that to the "Automatically start this workflow whenever an item is changed" and so it triggers multiple workflows (not really what I want) but when I changed the status to resolved, I got my e-mail!!! so I'm partway there.

I guess I need the workflow to start when the item is created, but not "complete" until the status has been changed to resolved. Thoughts?

Comment: no, it won't trigger multiple workflows, everytime there is modification to the list item it will essentially ask the data, "Is the status resolved?" yes = email, and no just means it will complete without sending an email.

Comment: BTW you can add both checkboxes. 

Automatically start this workflow whenever an item is changed

AND

Automatically start this workflow whenever an item is created

Comment: [editorial suggestion] Does the comment above work as a solution? Post it as an answer so that it may be marked as "Answered".

Answer (score 0):

> I changed that to the "Automatically start this workflow whenever an
>   item is changed" and so it triggers multiple workflows (not really
>   what I want) but when I changed the status to resolved, I got my
>   e-mail!!! so I'm partway there. I guess I need the workflow to start
>   when the item is created, but not "complete" until the status has been
>   changed to resolved. Thoughts?

There is a Workflow Action in the Workflow designer called "Wait for Field Change in Current Item". I think it will do what you are look for.